# Find Correlations

Tags: r, correlation

I have average response rates (response) for sending and getting emails back for 37 countries(country), now I have to find out if these avg. responserates correlate with any of the index which are also on country level from Dahlström (link below). There are 2500 variables in this dataset. I would like to find high (>0.7) and low(<-0.7) correlations with my average response rate. Is there some trick to do so?

b is the dataset where I have the responserate and country that intrests,
country is the variable needed to merge with the other dataset

```
    > head(b)
        country  computer friendliness      age money_dummy     busy
    1 Argentina 0.7375000     4.570000 3.402500   0.5000000 2.222500
    2 Australia 0.9699248     4.050125 3.187970   0.4987469 2.511278
    3    Brazil 0.7568922     4.714286 3.340852   0.5012531 2.310777
    4    Canada 0.9675000     3.912500 3.417500   0.5000000 2.135000
    5     China 0.4375000     4.825000 3.180000   0.5000000 1.990000
    6   Croatia 0.8533333           NA 3.626667   0.5000000 0.550000
       response avg_managementscore people_room      male
    1 0.4750000            2.682062    2.012500 0.5350000
    2 0.6065163            2.998608    2.368421 0.4285714
    3 0.4135338            2.661259    2.120301        NA
    4 0.5500000            3.142591    2.030000 0.3850000
    5 0.1425000            2.685837    1.802500 0.4675000
    6 0.5933333                  NA    1.556667 0.4033333*
```

http://qog.pol.gu.se/data/datadownloads/qogstandarddata

Comment: http://www.statmethods.net/stats/correlations.html  You can also make a correlation matrix or use an apply or sapply statement with a correlation function.

Comment: I didn't download Dahlström data but is there a variable for country with similar encoding - the first step is to have a matching key (ISOcode or whatever). The use `merge(b, dahlstromdata,by=country, all.x=TRUE)` and use `cor` function